# Can I get a list of helpful hints during the load screen

Tags: torchlight-2

Is there a file or a website I can look at to read all the helpful hints given during the load screen?  Sometimes they go by very fast and I don't get to finish reading them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Link to Post](https://forum.quartertothree.com/t/torchlight-2-release-thread/70534/169)

Ugly Formatting but here are the hints.

- Click on the Send Pet To Town icon in your pet's inventory or near his health badge to send them off to sell your excess items, so that you can keep adventuring.
- Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> to see any items scattered on the ground, or toggle this view with the magnifying glass icon.
- Use the mouse-wheel to zoom in and out.
- Clicking the mouse-wheel button will reset your view.
- Holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while attacking will force you to remain in place during combat.
- Holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while clicking on an item will cause your pet to run and pick it up.
- Holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while clicking on an item in a Merchant screen will instantly sell or
  buy it.
- Unidentified items may be identified by using an identify scroll. Right-click on the item to identify it if and it will automatically use any identify scrolls you have.
- Left-click on monsters to attack them.
- Hold the left mouse button down to continuously attack.
- Right-click to use your currently assigned skill or spell. You can also use TAB to switch between it and an alternate skill, noted on the right skill interface at the bottom of the screen.
- When you gain a level, remember to assign any points you may have earned to improve your player's attributes. These attributes increase damage and improve defenses.
- Feed fish to your pet to turn them into creatures with varying abilities, strengths, and weaknesses.
- Press <kbd>M</kbd> to toggle the minimap, and use the <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> keys to zoom in and out.
- Some equipment can only be used if you meet level or stat requirements.
- Requirements you don't currently meet are displayed in red.
- If you find yourself dying too much, try to increase your armor. Higher armor equipment reduces damage that monsters deal to you.
- Elemental Armors, like Fire Armor, help reduce the elemental damage you take, as well as reducing the chance of harmful effects, like Burning.
- Purple Damage numbers mean you have 'fumbled' the attack, which reduces damage. Press <kbd>J</kbd> to view the Arcane Statistics Panel and learn about this and other combat
  mechanics.
- Your Pet can now buy basic items like potions and scrolls from town. Check out the fourth tab in your pet's inventory to access the Shopping List. Items purchased this way will be added to your inventory when your pet returns.
- Green items have minor enchantments. Blue items are more rare and powerful. Gold items are unique and have the best enchantments. Purple items are related to quests.
- Holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while attacking will only move you or use a skill if you have a target highlit. This is useful to prevent inadvertent movement during fast combat.
- If you find good loot which your character can't use, consider trading it with another player or keeping it in your Shared Stash for your other characters to use.
- If you are wielding two similar weapons, like any two melee weapons or two pistols, you have a chance to Execute, striking with both weapons at one time. Investing in your Focus attribute improves this chance.
- Passive skills are always in effect, but sometimes you need to have the right weapon equipped.
- In Multi-Player games, the monsters you fight will do more damage to you and take more damage to defeat, based on the numbers of players nearby. Those nearby players will also get full experience for each monster killed.
- In Multi-Player games, any loot that you find will be visible only to you. Feel free to take everything! The other players will get their own loot.
- Claw weapons are fast, but don't hit adjacent monsters. Hammers tend to be slow but interrupt monster attacks and skills. Axes do more consistent damage. Polearms have longer range.
- Most melee weapons do Splash Damage, hitting adjacent monsters in an arc in front of you. Two-handed weapons have longer and wider arcs and do a larger amount of damage to these Splash targets.
- Cannons and Shotgonnes attack multiple enemies in wide, but short arcs. Crossbows have the longest range. Pistols are fast, but have shorter range. Bows have an average range.
- Wands and Staves do mostly elemental damage, which tends to be useful for Embermage skills and perhaps any character investing in Focus.
- Remember to feed Fish to your Pet! It will make your pet stronger and give you a critical combat boost when the going gets tough.
- Look for fishing holes in the wilderness.
- The damage you do is reduced by your target's Armor; more Armor means less damage. Attacks can score a Critical Hit, doing extra damage. Check the Arcane Statistics panel for more combat details.
- Most enchanters can enchant any item two times. Others are more skilled and can grant a third or fourth enchantment! Enchanters can also remove existing enchantments allowing items to be enchanted again.
- Don't save your Ember for later! Use them in any piece of equipment with an open Socket. You will find better varieties soon, and the ancient art of combining gems to make better ones has been lost in this era.
- Higher level monsters do more Damage and have more Armor and Health. These key combat statistics make fighting monsters above your own an increasingly difficult task.
- The <kbd>Z</kbd> key will drink your best Health Potion. The <kbd>X</kbd> key will drink your best Mana Potion. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> key will heal your pet instead of you.
- Press the <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> to quickly close any currently open interface panels. If no panels are open, instead it will access your Inventory and Character panels.
- When quest items are picked up, they are stored in your Quest Log <kbd>Q</kbd>, not in your inventory.
- Fire damage can randomly cause enemies to Burn, doing extra damage over 3 to 7 seconds. Burning bypasses armor and is good for taking down tougher enemies.
- Ice damage can randomly cause enemies to Freeze, slowing their attacks, skills and movement by 33% for 3 to 4 seconds.
- Electrical damage has a chance to randomly Shock enemies for 3 to 5 seconds. When you hit a shocked target, the impact releases 3 small Charged Bolts that can strike multiple targets up to10 meters away.
- Poison damage has a chance to randomly Poison enemies, reducing their armor and damage dealing by 33% for 3 to 5 seconds.